# How to operate logic operation of all columns of a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have the following `2D` `NumPy` array consisting of four rows and three columns:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([[True, False],[False, False], [True, False]])
>>> array([[ True, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

What would be an efficient way to generate a `1D` array that contains the logic or of all columns (like `[True, False]`)?

I searched the web and found someone referring to `sum(axis=)` to calculate the `sum`.

I wonder if there is some similar way for logic operation?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, there is. Use `any`:

```
>>> a = np.array([[True, False],[False, False], [True, False]])
>>> a
array([[ True, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> a.any(axis=0)
array([ True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Note what happens when you change the argument `axis` to `1`:

```
>>> a.any(axis=1)
array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
>>>
```

If you want logical-and use `all`:

```
>>> b.all(axis=0)
array([False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> b.all(axis=1)
array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>>
```

Also note that if you leave out the `axis` keyword argument, it works across every element:

```
>>> a.any()
True
>>> a.all()
False
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include `b` in your example: `b = np.array([[True, True],[False, False], [True, False]])`

Answer (score 6):

NumPy has also a [`reduce`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) function which is similar to Python's [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce). It's possible to use it with NumPy's [logical operations](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.logic.html#logical-operations). For example:

```
>>> a = np.array([[True, False],[False, False], [True, False]])
>>> a
array([[ True, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True, False]])
>>> np.logical_or.reduce(a)
array([ True, False])
>>> np.logical_and.reduce(a)
array([False, False])
```

It also has the `axis` parameter:

```
>>> np.logical_or.reduce(a, axis=1)
array([ True, False,  True])
>>> np.logical_and.reduce(a, axis=1)
array([False, False, False])
```

The idea of `reduce` is that it cumulatively applies a function (in our case `logical_or` or `logical_and`) to each row or column.